# Can't use line breaks for facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Ok so my applications creates an event on behalf of the user. I got everything figured out except for the fact that when my user enters the event description on my app (in a textbox) and i send the info to facebook as a post, facebook does not interpret the \n or \r as line breaks but escapes them.

I understand not allowing html tags in your strings, but not event linebreaks!!! I tried using  base on earlier posts but facebook patched this bug and it no longer works.

Anyone out there who has an idea on how to incoperate line breaks!! Can i modify the facebook sdk somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the Facebook Graph API.  People have found a couple hack workarounds but then Facebook patches those and they stop working.  It would be best to log this as a feature request on their new bug tracker tool.